# Users with Windows domain accounts get EPERM error when accessing files in C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming

Tags: windows, electron

We maintain an Electron application that stores files in the users' profiles (C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\OUR_APP) and later needs to access them again.

Users who use domain accounts to login into Windows and whose profiles are synced across machines encounter permission issues when our application tries to access the files in this directory. We use Sentry and see lots of error reports like this:
[image: error report]

I suspect that this is caused by Windows locking files when it syncs the contents of the AppData\Roaming directory. The strange thing is that the errors we're seeing don't happen when we write these files but when we want to read them (lstat in the screenshot below).

Has anyone encountered this issues with profile data in Windows before and can confirm that this might be cause by the sync process? Are applications expected work around these errors? Are there documented limitations of data you can put into the AppData\Roaming directory?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using `%appdata%`. Instead, try:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming
```

Comment: We get the path from Electron's getPath function, which abstracts getting the profile path for the various OSes. The path in the screenshot also is correctly resolved and it should be valid. The files in question were also written to the path by the application which uses the same base path.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking at this: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6628 
what is your app.path set to? Thanks

Comment: app.path doesn't exist on Electron's app object. As I said in the original question, I think it has to do with locking and syncing and not with the resolution of the actual path. All the full paths in the Sentry issues look like proper correctly resolved paths.

Comment: May I ask what the permissions are locally of the account being used as a service account? If you log in as that windows profile, can you access said path? Thanks -

Comment: I can't say, as this problem only occurs on the end-users' machines, which I don't have access to.

Comment: Sebastian, You must build a test machine for your workflow buddy...